# jQuery undocumented function?

Tags: jquery

right click on an element :  ( **no** using plugins)

I saw an answer like this :

```
$('#hello').bind("contextmenu",function(e){    //contextmenu ??
   alert('Right Clickz');
   return false;
});
```

I've searched all jquery site and didnt find the `contextmenu` function.

**where** is it documented ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `bind()` method takes the name of a DOM event which is any event supported by the DOM tree jQuery is running with, including your own custom events. All events for all browsers are not documented and all events will not exist in all browsers.

See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Some of the events have shortcuts and probably works in the majority of browsers.

For more possible DOM events google for "dom event list".

Answer (score 1):

This site shows what browsers and objects the event is available on (almost all):

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html

> The contextmenu event fires when the user calls the context menu by right-clicking.

This handy demo page shows it in action:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/contextmenu.html